# How to reliably download dividend information

Tags: r, quantmod

I am using the package `quantmod` to download stock information for investing. Part of this package is `getDividends`. For example, to load dividends paid by a company, this is how I would do it:

```
library(quantmod)
getDividends("F")
```

The problem is that it does not always load the most recent information. Example:

```
getDividends("TM")
```

While we can look up that there is a more recent dividend info available online: http://performance.morningstar.com/stock/performance-return.action?p=dividend_split_page&t=TM

Is there any way to fix this, or some other way in R to reliably download the dividend information?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the `quantmod` [documentation](http://www.quantmod.com/documentation/getDividends.html) for `getDividends`, "data source (only yahoo is valid at present)".

This may by irrelevant, but with a Bloomberg terminal you can easily pull data straight into R using the `Rblpapi` library.